# Proof request: a collection of sliced squares of size 1 to n can always form a nontrivial rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, alternative-proof

I'm an active member and challenge writer on [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Here is a challenge of mine, titled [Make a rectangle from a collection of (sliced) squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203446/78410):

> ### Task
>
> There is a famous formula on the sum of first $n$ squares:
>
> $$ 1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $$
>
> It is known that this number is composite for any $n \ge 3$.
>
> Now, imagine a collection of row tiles (a tile of shape $1 \times k$
>   with the number $k$ written on each cell), and you have 1 copy of
>   size-1 tile, 2 copies of size-2 tiles, ... and $n$ copies of
>   size-$n$ tiles.
>
> ```
> [1]  [2 2]  [2 2]  [3 3 3]  [3 3 3]  [3 3 3] ...
> ```
>
> Then arrange them into a rectangle whose width and height are both $\ge 2$. You can place each tile horizontally or vertically.
>
> ```
> +-----+---+-+-+
> |3 3 3|2 2|1|2|
> +-----+---+-+ |
> |3 3 3|3 3 3|2|
> +-----+-----+-+
> ```
>
> Output such a matrix if it exists. [...]

I added a conjecture on the task:

> **I believe there exists a solution for any $n \ge 3$.**

Then an answerer came up with a [constructive proof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203451/78410) that it is possible to form a nontrivial rectangle **using only horizontal tiles**:

> It's an incremental construction. Consider $n \bmod 6$, we can have
>   these values for height and width of rectangles:
>
> - $n/6\times (n+1)(2n+1)~(n\bmod 6=0)$
> - $(2n+1)/3\times n(n+1)/2~(n\bmod 6=1)$
> - $(n+1)/3\times n(2n+1)/2~(n\bmod 6=2)$
> - $n/3\times (n+1)(2n+1)/2~(n\bmod 6=3)$
> - $(2n+1)/3\times (n+1)n/2~(n\bmod 6=4)$
> - $(n+1)/6\times n(2n+1)~(n\bmod 6=5)$
>
> (dimensions might be $1$ for $n\leq 6$ so these small cases are
>   handled manually)
>
> So the main idea of my construction is:
>
> - We construct rectangles with the heights and widths as in above list.
> - If $n\bmod 3 \neq 1$, construct the solution for $n-6$ recursively, add in $n-5,n-4\cdots n$. The height of the rectangle
>     will only increase 1 or 2.
> - If $n\bmod 3=1$, construct the solution for $n-3$ recursively and add in $n-2,n-1,n$. The height of the rectangle will only
>     increase 2.
> - We first carefully assign the new numbers to the added columns, and then put rest of the numbers into one or two added rows.
>
> The rest of the job is some careful casework to pick the numbers. [...]

While this proof solves the question at hand, it isn't as elegant as we expected. So here is the question: **Can we find a more mathematical (and less case analysis based) proof that such a solution exists for any $n \ge 3$?** It doesn't need to be restricted to horizontal tiles.

Edit: As the question isn't getting any sign of progress, I'm also open to any proof (not necessarily elegant) that is distinct from the one above.

Comment: Given the fact that which factors in $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ could possibly absorb the factors of the denominator $6$ depends on $n$ modulo $6$, in some sense all solutions whose rectangle dimensions have simple formulas in terms of $n$ must look something like the solution you described.

Comment: It's interesting that the other solutions on CodeGolf tend towards random/greedy.  As I was thinking about this (and eventually agreeing with @MarkS.), I found that $\sum_{k=1}^{24} k^2 = 4900 = 70^2$ but the 24 squares $1 \times 1$, $2 \times 2$, $\ldots$, $24 \times 24$ cannot tile a $70 \times 70$ square.  See this [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133348/consecutive-integer-squared-square).